# Apache Wicket TextField

Tags: wicket, textfield

Good day!
I create some Table:

```
List<IColumn<User, String>> columns = new ArrayList<>();

columns.add(new AbstractColumn<User, String>(new Model<String>("")) {

        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<User>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<User> rowModel) {
            cellItem.add(new Link<String>(componentId) {

                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    System.out.println("editors" + rowModel.getObject().getName());
                    PageParameters parameters = new PageParameters();
                    parameters.add("id", rowModel.getObject().getId());
                    add(new EditPanel("panel", rowModel));

                }

                @Override
                public IMarkupFragment getMarkup() {
                    return Markup.of("<div wicket:id='cell'> edit </div>");
                }
            });

        }
```

When I click on cell into Table, cell markup "Edit", I create some Panel:

```
public class EditPanel extends Panel {

public EditPanel(String id, IModel<User> model) {
    super(id, model);

    User user = model.getObject();
    if (user == null) {
        user = new User();
    }

    List<UserRole> list = Arrays.asList(UserRole.values());

    Form<?> form = new Form("form", new CompoundPropertyModel(user));

    TextField<String> userName = new TextField<String>("name");

    };

    add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));
    add(form);
    form.add(userName);

}
```

}

How can I set value to 
TextField userName = new TextField("name");
from my model, or if model == null, set any text what I need?
Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using `CompoundPropertyModel` try to give entity name as text field name .i.e if your user model is  username then You should specify `new TextField("username")`then you don't rely on fields

Answer (score 0):

If you use Wicket 7 or older then you may use :

```
TextField<String> userName = new TextField<String>("name", new PropertyModel(model, "username"));
```

assuming that `username` is a property of `User`.

With Wicket 8.x you can use `LambdaModel` instead.

Comment: Why the `CompoundPropertyModel`?I think `PropertyModel` is better here (or indeed even better, the Wicket 8 `LambdaModel`)

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, 
I think the problem is because you are passing the object and not the model.

The right way is passing with CompoundPropertyModel, like you do. It`s better then PropertyModel in this case.

Try doing this:

```
...
    if (model.getObject() == null) {
        model.setObject(new User());
    }
 Form<?> form = new Form("form", new CompoundPropertyModel(model));
...
```

Hope help you.